# ...each with... (Absolute clauses)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, absolute-clauses

> For earlier generations, buying food or consumer products involved
>   visiting several shops, ***each with the same limited range on
>   offer***. ([Source](https://www.ielts-exam.net/ielts_writing_samples_task_2/1015/).)

Is marked phrase an absolute clause?

I have made an another example with the same construction I think. Is that sentence below correct?

> The choir consisted of five people, ***each with a unique voice***.

Answer (score 1):

No these are not absolute clauses. They do not use a participle as their verb, nor do they include their own subject. In the first the subject is "several shops", in the second it is "five people".

As [this article on absolute clauses](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/absolute-clause) says:

> Outside a few set phrases such as *all being/going well*, *weather permitting*, *present company excluded/excepted*, absolute clauses are infrequent and usually confined to formal written English.

My understanding is that:

- an absolute clause (which some call an absolute phrase) will always include a noun or noun phrase, which serves as the subject of the clause;
- usually an absolute clause will include a past or present participle, which serves as the verb of the clause;
- when an absolute clause does not include a particple, it will not include any verb at all;
- An absolute clause always modifies an entire sentence, or an entire independent clause (which could be a full sentence), not merely a single noun or noun phrase;
- an absolute clause may include additional modifiers, but need not do so.

---

by the way, the 2nd example (before the edit corrected it):

> The choir was consist of five people, each with a unique voice.

is incorrect. It should be one of:

> - The choir consisted of five people, each with a unique voice.
> - The choir was composed of five people, each with a unique voice.
> - The choir was made up of five people, each with a unique voice.

but not "was consisted" nor "was consist".

Comment: So are they reduced clauses? "The choir consisted of five people, ***who each*** was with a unique voice. "  or "The choir consisted of five people, ***each of whom*** was with a unique voice." + As far as I know absolute phrases don't have to use a participle as their verb. For example: "The man stood laughing, his weapons at his hips." (Stephen Crane, "The Bride Comes to Yellow Sky") (Link: https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049)

Comment: @Talha Özden I would say that that quote from Crane does not contain an absolute clause. I would further say that many of the examples in the  thoughtco.com article are not absolute clauses either. A number of them modify nouns or verbs, not entire independent clauses, and several contain verbs that are not participles. But I am not sure how helpful it is to identify a part of a sentence as an absolute clause. What is more important, I think, is what a clasue modifies, a word or the whole independent clause